# Is there a quick way to unequip a spent Mantle?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

After the effects of a Mantle run out, the hunter will keep wearing it even though it is no longer providing any benefit. As a side effect, the Mantle's cooldown won't start recharging until it is actually unequipped.

It is possible to unequip a Mantle by selecting it as an item again, but I'm wondering if there's a faster way to unequip a Mantle after its effects have expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mantles will also automatically unequip if spent when your hunter sheaths their weapon after combat.

Comment: More like when weapon is sheathed and you leave combat, then it unequipps automatically. Right now your answer can be read as that you specifically need to sheathe the weapon after leaving combat to trigger that action

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you just use the item again the Hunter will unequip it and the cooldown will begin.

Be careful though, because if you put the mantle on and then quickly take it off again, you still have to wait the full cooldown.

Other than just using the nav-wheel, there is no way to automatically take it off when it expires (right now... this could change, or be an armor skill later on)

Comment: I'm positive I've had Mantles unequip on their own at some point after their effect had expired, so I'm not convinced there's really no other way to do it.

Comment: I think what this answer means is there's no other way to *manually* remove it other than selecting it on the Nav wheel or the item bar. It'll remove itself automatically after some time, but that'll eat up more time until you can use it again.